# How can I move a Websphere node to a new deployment manager

Tags: websphere, wsrr

I have a deployment manager that is on an older version of WebSphere than the wsrr node. For this reason the node has been unable to sync with the deployment manager. For complicated reasons, I can't just upgrade the deployment manager and re-sync.

I have built a new deployment manager on the same version as the node and would like to sync the existing node with the new deployment manager. I will need to keep all applications, buses, data sources, etc. from the existing node.

Is there an easy way to move an existing managed node to a new deployment manager?

edit: this is on linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant move node from one deployment manager to the other. The Dmgr is a master here. If you remove node from one, the node will be reverted to status from before federation, so you will loose all what was configured via Dmgr.

You always have to first upgrade deployment manager.

If you are doing version upgrade (not fixpack, eg. from 8.5.5.x to v9) then you can use migration tools to migrate Dmgr. If you cant just upgrade your existing Dmgr, you can choose remote migration scenario and migrate it to the new environment, keeping the old one as is.

The other option would be to export (via wsadmin task) current Dmgr configuration and import to the new one (although it will not copy all possible settings) and then recreate node (`addNode -asExistingNode`).

And if you have WSRR installed then you have to consult WSRR documentation regarding migration, just migrating WAS might be not enough.

Comment: Thank you, based on your response, I found the IBM documentation on remote migration!